# Installing R-package from CRAN does not include Bioconductor packages

Tags: r, cran, bioconductor

I have an R-package on CRAN. When I install it, using `install.packages("mypackage")`, I get the warning message `Warning in install.packages : dependencies ‘x’, ‘y’ are not available`, with x and y being packages on Bioconductor. This leads to functions in my package using functions from x and y not working.

This problem seem to have appeared out of nowhere (maybe when I updated my own R-version?), and only affects Bioconductor Imports, not CRAN Imports. Packages x and y are perfectly functional, and if I install them separately using `BiocManager::install(c("x", "y"))` my package works as it should. My package passes all checks in CRAN. As suggested [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/r-package-development-how-does-one-automatically-install-bioconductor-packages) I have `biocViews:` in my package `DESCRIPTION`. After some research, my best guess is that maybe the problem is due to mismatches between R and Bioconductor releases, as described [here](https://bioconductor.org/install/#why-biocmanagerinstall), although I have to say, I don't fully understand this.

Any ideas on why I have this problem, and how to fix it? Currently, my best solution is to add instructions to the readme that the Bioconductor packages may need to be downloaded separately, but that is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Just a guess, did you try `BiocManager::install("mypackage")` ?

Comment: I actually think `biocViews:` is no longer required anyway.

Comment: @zx8754. `BiocManager::install("mypackage")` worked and installed the Bioconductor packages as well. I guess asking users to install my package with this function rather than the standard `install.packages("mypackage")` is a good enough solution then. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `BiocManager` to install the CRAN package, as it can install both CRAN and bioconductor packages:

```
BiocManager::install("mypackage")
```